# I can not take value from MemoryCache

Tags: c#

I can not take any data from MemoryCache. The following code is not working:

```
List<Product> result = GetDataWithAdoNet();

var cache = new MemoryCache("demoCaching");
var cacheItem = new CacheItem("fullName", result);
var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(60.0)
};

var cacheAdd = cache.Add(cacheItem, cacheItemPolicy);
var result2 = cache.GetCacheItem("fullName");
Console.WriteLine(result2.Value + " " + result2.Key);

Console.ReadLine();
```

I am taking records (string = ProductName, decimal = UnitPrice) with the GetDataWithAdoNet method from Northwind database

`result2.Value` seems to have 106 data items, but I can't reach records inside `result2.Value`. The `result2.Value` is also not working inside a foreach loop. What should I do?

Comment: define "not working".

Comment: The Add method of a MemoryCache has 3 parameters.  You are passing your expiration policy as your value parameter instead of the expiration parameter.

Comment: The type of `result2.Value` is object, you should just cast `result2.Value` to `List<product>`

Comment: When you have code that doesn't work, like _The '' is also not working inside a foreach loop._ then you should include an example of how you are calling it in the loop, also including the result of your `Console.WriteLine` debug statements would help a lot without us having to compile and execute your partial code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you casting the `Cacheitem.Value` to `List<Product>`?

```
// prepare cache

List<Product> result = new List<Product>() { new Product(), new Product() };

var cache = new MemoryCache("demoCaching");
var cacheItem = new CacheItem("fullName", result);
var cacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(60.0)
};

var cacheAdd = cache.Add(cacheItem, cacheItemPolicy);

// read cache

var cacheItem2 = cache.GetCacheItem("fullName");

if (cacheItem2 != null)
{
    List<Product> result2 = (List<Product>)cacheItem2.Value;

    foreach (var product in result2)
    {

    }
}
else
{
    // Cache item not found
}
```

Because on my pc it works correctly.